Line integral with respect to the arc length
Find $$\int_{C}\phi\,ds$$ in the counterclockwise direction, where $\phi(x,y)=x+y$ and $s$ is the arc length. Here $C$ is the line joining $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.
Solutions I tried:
Sol 1: Let $\alpha(t)=(t,1-t),\,0\leq t\leq 1$ be the line joining the two points $\alpha(1)=(1,0)$ and $\alpha(0)=(0,1)$. Then $\alpha'(t)=(1,-1)$. So the required integral will be
$$
\int_{1}^{0}\|\alpha'(t)\|\,dt=\int_{1}^{0}\sqrt{2}\,dt=-\sqrt{2}.
$$
Sol 2: Let $\alpha(t)=(1-t,t),\,0\leq t\leq 1$ be the line joining the two points $\alpha(0)=(1,0)$ and $\alpha(1)=(0,1)$. Then $\alpha'(t)=(-1,1)$. So the required integral will be
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\|\alpha'(t)\|\,dt=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{2}\,dt=\sqrt{2}.
$$
The actual answer is $-\sqrt{2}$, but I could not understand why Sol 2 is wrong. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Who claims that the actual answer is $-\sqrt{2},?$

This is from the book of Tom Apostle, Vol II. Answer is $-\sqrt{2}$. What is the actual answer according to you? Both cannot be the answer, right?

Indeed, Tom Apostol writes on p. 647 of Calculus Volume II that the solution to Exercise 10.9. 7 on p. 331 is $-\sqrt{2},.$ I think that's wrong. Line integrals of scalar fields should not depend on the direction. See also this post. Besides: in the exercise Apostol wants us to calculate the integral around the entire triangle with vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),.$ The result of that should be $1+\sqrt{2},.$

Thanks. Then what is wrong in my sol 1 and Sol 2? Both cannot be correct, right, since answers are different. Kindly explain.

What led you in Solution one to  integrate from $1$ to $0,?$ Apostol is not totally wrong. Nowhere in his definitions I find that rule. For further details I finally refer to the post I linked to already. You should digest that patiently.

Thanks a lot. Sol 1, from 1 to 0 I did, since at t=1, we get the initial point and at t=0, the end point since it is in the counterclockwise direction. Am I missing something?

You do not seem to read the link where in large fonts and bold letters precisely that question is answered.

Ok. I will look more carefully. Thanks again.
